# scp from Raspberry pi to SSH Server, "lost connection"

Tags: ssh

I am trying to copy a private key from my raspberry pi to an SSH Server (my Android phone, via [SimpleSSHD app](http://www.galexander.org/software/simplesshd/)).

I can successfully ssh in to the server from the Pi with:

```
ssh 192.168.0.123 -p 2222
```

But when I do, I have to enter a password that the SimpleSSHD app shows on the (Android) screen

From the doc (linked above), I am trying to add a private key so I don't have to enter a password every time I SSH into the server:

> If SimpleSSHD does not find an authorized_keys file when a client connects, then it generates a single-use password at that time and displays it in the console log. So the procedure to login the first time is to initiate the ssh connection, then look at the phone and type in the password that is on the screen in the SimpleSSHD app. It is recommended to use that shell session to install the authorized_keys file.
>
> Once authorized_keys exists, only public key authentication is supported. If you screw up your authorized_keys file, use the options menu (upper right) -> Reset Keys.
>
> The default home directory is now the app-private directory, which will generally be something like /data/data/org.galexander.sshd/files...

In the app, it shows that the App-private path is: `/data/user/0/org.galexander.sshd/files`

So, on my RPi, in a terminal I did:

```
ssh-keygen
```

and when I do `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, I get this output:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB2Naz[long string of random letters/numbers]ASDFG pi@raspberrypi
```

So I know I have created a private key.

Now, in the RPi terminal, I did:

```
ssh 192.168.0.123 -p 2222
```

And entered the password the SimpleSSHD app creates.  Then, I created the `authorized_keys` folder in the HOME directory, as the docs linked above state...I think:

```
mkdir ~/authorized_keys
```

Now, I think all I need to do is copy the RPi's `id_rsa.pub` to the SimpleSSHD folder, right?, so I tried this from the RPi terminal:

```
scp -P 2222 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@192.168.0.123:~/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub
```

But when I do I get this returned in the RPi Terminal:

```
id_rsa.pub        0%   0    0.0KB/s --:-- ETAlost connection
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've made sure I have updated `openssh-clients`, as I saw in [this Question](https://superuser.com/questions/577911/scp-lost-connection-but-ssh-works-fine)

Finally, to note, the SimpleSSHD docs say explicitly `Create authorized_keys in the home directory (do not use ssh-copy-id)`, so I am not using `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but perhaps `authorized_keys` should be a **file** that you *create by* copying the `id_rsa.pub` file. By creating it first (as a directory) perhaps you disabled password-based authentication (as the guide says *"Once authorized_keys exists, only public key authentication is supported. If you screw up your authorized_keys file, use the options menu (upper right) -> Reset Keys."*)

Comment: @steeldriver so would I just skip the `mkdir` part? So should I delete the folder first and just skip to `scp ...`?

Comment: That's the way I'm reading it - i.e. `scp -P 2222 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub pi@192.168.0.123:~/authorized_keys`. Yes you would need to delete the folder first. This would also be more consistent with the OpenSSH setup where `authorized_keys` is a file (albeit inside a `~/.ssh/` subdirectory rather than in the home directory itself).

Comment: @steeldriver this makes so much sense because searching online I always see reference to `.ssh`, but it seems this app specifically uses another folder. I'll try shortly and get back *crosses fingers*

Comment: @steeldriver - So, I SSH'ed in to the SSH Server, then did `rm -r ~/authorized_keys` to remove the directory. Then, in the Pi terminal, `scp -P 2222 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@192.168.0.123:~/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub`, and then get the notice `/data/user/0/org.galexander.sshd/files/authorized_keys/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory`...but I know `/data/user/0/org.galexander.sshd/files` exists because if I do `ls ~/`, it changes to that directory...